# How to add CSS to ASP.NET site with WebOptimization and Bundling

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I created a ASP.NET forms site as a sandbox and I used NuGet to add Bootstrap, which I'm just now learning. I wanted to change the theme, so I downloaded a theme and renamed the minimized file as theme1-bootstrap.min.css.  If I simply replace the existing boostrap.min.css, everything works as expected.

However, I was thinking (possibly incorrectly) that it this is not a good idea, that its better to load my themed bootstrap.min.css after the original bootstrap.min.css.  This is what the reference I'm using does with a  statement in an html file.

But the ASP.NET project is a bit different then the html reference I'm using, and I can't find any  statements anywhere.  I'm figuring it has something to do with Bundle.config or the line in the site.master
    `<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />`

I'd appreciate just knowing what's going on and what's the best practice for applying my theme.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at ~/AppStart/BundleConfig.cs:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

This means that Web Optimization will search for files `bootstrap.css` and `site.css` as it is or with `.min` suffix.
So if you need to add `theme1-bootstrap.min.css` to the bundle - you need to extend it like this:

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/site.css",
              "~/Content/theme1-bootstrap.css"));
```